# Create exe to update the files

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, exe

I have to update values in xml file after msi installation.
The updating of files has to run silently without any user prompt and without TargetDir creation.
So the exe which i have to create has to only update file without user noticing it.
Wanted some methods on how to go about this problem

Comment: You mean during the installation you have to update some values in a xml file ?

Comment: After the installation

Comment: Let me get it, that means when user install the application through MSI it should first deploy the app and at the end it should update a xml file ?

Comment: xml file is updated based on the users specific settings or environment ?

Comment: Do you need something like this?: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-import-edit-xml-file.html